# lInstalling custom terminal font on linux mint 19.1

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, fonts, linux-mint

I'm trying to install Roboto Mono as the font on my bash terminal in Linux Mint 19.1 -- and the option to customize fonts using `Edit -> Preferences -> Custom Font` doesn't seem to allow me to specify a new font that is not pre-installed.

Is this because the terminal does not allow for .ttf fonts to be used as a custom font, or is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's a "bash terminal"? Did you mean gnome-terminal instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not about a font being pre-installed or not.

GNOME Terminal only offers you monospace fonts to choose from in its Preferences dialog. However, you can pick any font in `dconf-editor`. Navigate to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:` followed by the Profile ID, and then set it under `font`.

It seems to require further investigation why Roboto Mono isn't assumed to be monospace font.